# How to submit a Slurm job from local machine to GPU cluster?

Tags: slurm, sbatch

I wanted to know is it possible to submit a Slurm job from my local machine without logging into the GPU cluster? For example: Everytime when I need to submit a job I have to copy the executable files to the GPU cluster directory and then `sbatch` the job. Would it be possible that I can submit the job from my local machine rather than copying the files to the GPU cluster?